# why exactly should I put the ellipsis inside the parameter of a function?

Tags: php

What is the real purpose of function with ellipsis in its parameter?

I have this function:

```
class Dog{
    public function type(...$numbers){
        var_dump($numbers);
    }
}
```

and this function

```
class Dog{
    public function type($numbers){
        var_dump($numbers);
    }
}
```

Whether I put ellipsis or not, if I call the type function putting multiple parameters in it, its type will always be an array.

So my question is, why exactly should I put the ellipsis inside the parameter of a function?

Comment: The type depends on how you call it in the second.  How are you calling your functions?

Comment: How do you call this function with multiple arguments?

Comment: its called a variadic see- http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics

Comment: It can be useful for things like this  `$array = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4, 'b']]; print_r(array_merge(...$array));`  output `[1,'a',2,'b',3,'c',4,'d']` especially if you don't know how long `$array` is.  here is a better link http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list  In the past we had to use things like `func_get_args()` and `call_user_func_array('function', $args)` etc.  which is pretty ugly compared to this `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar, called [variable-length argument lists](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). It lets you pass the function multiple arguments that it will turn into an array automatically. In that example, it would let you call `type(1, 2, 3)` and `$numbers` would be an array of those three numbers.